# Is there a popular C++ service framework?

Tags: c++

... like Remoting or WCF in C# or Java RMI?

I am learning c++ and need a simple to use tcp service framework with built in binary serialization for c++ to c++ communication.

Thanks

Comment: Any C++ RPC mechanism is going to be complicated, much more so than the equivalent in C# or Java. I wouldn't recommend using something like that to learn C++.

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) or Google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) are probably the two that will suit your needs the best.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to drop the 'simple' part. Try Corba (portable) or DCOM (almost only Windows).

Answer (score 0):

You could use boost [MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/mpi.html) but it's quite complex, however library for use in distributed-memory parallel application programming.

You could use more simpler solution for c++, implementing your own dispatchers using ie. protocol-buffers from google or even json. Then parsing it using some design patterns like 'command' to execute some methods.